# Stanford Ner : build my own model or use RegexNer?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like some advices for Stanford NER, I'm wondering what it is the best way to detect new entities :

- Use RegexNer to detect new entities ?
- Train my own NER model with new entities ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can easily generate a large list of the type of entity you want to tag, I would suggest using RegexNER.  For instance if you were trying to tag sports teams, it would probably be easier to just compile a large list of sports team names and directly match.  Building a large training set can take a lot of effort.